# How to solve mindset and value conflict?

Tags: conflict

I have an agile mindset / conflict mediation question.

There is a conflict between the PO (Product Owner) and me, the Scrum Master.

The PO is on some kind of crusade to appear to be the loudest, most visible, and busiest, most useful person in our department. I believe he is trying to be the alpha dog, commander, manager, the boss.

This is not at all how I think about my department. What I am trying to do with my work is elevate all people in dept so that everyone is more engaged and delivering more value.

He comes up with these digs in front of the team to try and make me look small, weak, like an idiot, ridicule me etc. For example, he will ask me if I am sick when I am not sick and haven't been sick. Or he will say he saw me in the office, but I wasn’t "working" or something like this.

Comment: Does the PO need to be at these meetings?

Comment: Isn't a key part of a Scrum Masters role to facilitate cooperation between members of a team? If so, what strategies have you already tried to resolve this conflict, and how have they not worked?

Comment: My head of deliver used to be like this. He used to make bold comments "Dont mislead the team" with out even understanding whats happening in meeting. Later after several months i felt that the team doesn't like me and hence they seem to escalate things to him on my back. So... How does your team take advices from you. Do they really like you? What does their work speak?

Comment: Yeah I would say they really like me but I think they feel the PO does more as he is like a command and control guy and appears to do more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do like [@Venture99's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/179159/114974).  But I want to provide an alternate path.

#### Don't be an easy target

Some people see workplace relationships only in a one-up, one-down fashion, and thus are constantly trying to be in the one-up position.  My recommendation in these situations is:  don't participate.

I find that people like this look for "easy targets."  This means that they look for people who respond to their digs and comments in a way that reinforces their perceived position.  So a comment that visibly makes you uncomfortable reinforces their views.  Likewise, a response that goes against their views tends to make them stop.  This type of person is close to the "Yeller," who likes to yell but seems to only yell at certain people - the people who react to the yelling.  If you don't react the way they like they leave to find someone easier to bully.

So if, for example, they ask you if you are sick when you aren't, respond with, "No, and I don't understand why you would ask me that."  If they say they saw you at your desk but not working, ask if they are now the productivity monitor.  Basically, stand up to the behavior and they'll find a new target to bother.

Comment: I really like this answer because it’s very aligned to my values and mindset

Comment: I was liking the answer until I read the last paragraph. That last paragraph is just feeding the troll. It creates the opportunity to engage in a back and forth which is what this person wants. That's how they "win" (in their mind). I think much simpler is to give this person absolutely nowhere to go. "Are you sick?" - Say in a very casual and dismissive tone - "Yep, completely and utterly." Then immediately jump into the next agenda topic or engage in some other action that dismisses the comment as completely unimportant and none of this person's business.

Answer (score 8):

#### TL;DR

The short answer is that

- You must resolve the conflict
- Resolution is almost impossible without confrontation
- How you approach the confrontation will determine your future working arrangement, there are numerous approaches you might want to consider
- If the conflict cannot be resolved than either the master or the dog will die

#### Either the Master or the Dog Will Die

This is an old parable, often used to describe long running military conflicts.  It is applicable to most situations.

A rich and powerful landowner was served by a faithful servant who catered to their every whim.  The master, approaching his elderly years, and impressed at the servants success let his entitlement go to far.

He asked the servant to teach his dog to speak or he would be dismissed with no wages and no pension.  The servant, facing an impossible task, asked for a few days to think about it.

The next day he approached the Master and said "English is a very hard language, it will take me 20 years to teach the dog to speak but I can do it.". The Master agreed and set a date 20 years hence.

The other house staff were aghast, they asked how the servant could accomplish such a task. He replied simply, the problem will resolve itself because "either the Master or the Dog will die."

#### Applicability to Your Situation

Forget Agile.  This is an interpersonal conflict in a professional situation.

If the conflict is not resolved either you or the Product Owner will leave your role, either voluntarily or via direct action.  In that regard, you are either the Master or the Dog and the PO is the other.  One of you will leave.

#### How to Resolve

Rapport building in delivery is crucial.  First off, is the PO using clumsy humour?  Maybe they are from a military, police or sports background where aggressive humour is the norm but does not translate well to a corporate environment?

If so, then rapport is even more crucial but you can respond in kind.   So, if he asks "Are you sick?" you can respond "why, you selling cough medicine or something"? Got a medical license I don't know about? Hey team, we need a new PO cause the old one leaving to resume his job as Chief of Medicine at Johns Hopkins."

This kind of grumpy-old-man humour is typical in locker rooms etc.

But let's assume the PO is being a genuinely toxic person to you.  Rapport building can break down that barrier.

**Your Dev team manage the code pipeline, your job is to manage the relationship pipeline.**

You should invest as much time in rapport building as you do in project administration.

Ask to speak to the Product Owner in an informal setting (coffee shop off-site etc) for a meeting.  Your aim is to ask the PO to articulate how YOU can better support THEM in their role.

- What do they expect from you?
- Are you exhibiting any behaviours that they find challenging?
- Are they confused about the PO or SM role?
- Are they under pressure?  Can you help that?
- Do they realise they are weakening your ability to support them as an SM by undermining you in front of the team?
- Do they have a lack of trust in the team?

Reaffirm your commitment to the team and to the product and to their decisions but ask them to help you in your role.  That you and the PO need to be aligned and supportive of each other.  It allows you to better support them in managing the product or service.

Be confident, not deferential.  Be direct, not antagonizing.

#### If it does not work

Either the Master or the Dog will die.

Escalate to your line manager that you have observed these behaviours, you have attempted to resolve them and build rapport but the PO is not forthcoming and being unprofessional.

From there, evaluate your options vis a vis another team or project.

#### Never Forget

We cannot all be friends at work, some personalities just won't get on, but we can all commit to the team and the mission and our colleagues well being, like you have described.  You have done nothing wrong.  Be confident in yourself.

Comment: *"In that regard, you are both the Master and the Dog."* - I think that's the point where the analogy fell down, especially as it implies the situation must be fatal for the OP!

Comment: Both - the OP is one and the PO is the other.   If the situation is not resolved, one will be leaving.  Not that the OP is both.

Comment: Ah well that explains it. I suppose you could have said "the pair of you are the..." or "you two are the...".

Comment: Yes, I could have written it more clearly.